# Create web display dashboard to fetch issues from project on Autodesk Docs

Tags: autodesk-forge

How to create web display dashboard fetch issues from project on Autodesk Docs with node.js or other language?

I was assigned by a supervisor to create a dashboard for displaying issues of project. Where can I find sample code or instructions?

Comment: On StackOverflow, you should better ask for solutions about problems you encounter trying to code your project. Providing error messages, logs, parts of your code and describing your difficulties, you will have more help from the community than just asking for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of help on the Autodesk Forge website :

1. In the [code-samples](https://forge.autodesk.com/code-samples) section
2. In the documentation itself for fetching [BIM360 issues](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/field-issues-GET/)

Then, on the learn forge website you have a section about how to create a [dashboard](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/dashboard).
Most of these examples are hosted on GitHub, so you can take a look at the [Autodesk-Forge](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge) repositories to get more resources.